# Verilog Comparator tree type

Tags: verilog

I m trying to simulate a tree type comparator for synthesis. It has two blocks and i used repetitive tasks to achieve it. But my test bench is showing errors . Can anybody try this

```
 module main_fn (A,B,G,L,E,g,l,e);
  input [31:0] A;
  input [31:0] B; 
  output [61:0]g;
  output [61:0]l;
  output [61:0]e;
  wire G_temp,E_temp,L_temp;
  output G,L,E;

  compare1 cp1_1(A[0],B[0],g[0],l[0],e[0]);
  compare1 cp1_2(A[l],B[l],g[1],l[1],e[1]);
  compare1 cp1_3(A[2],B[2],g[2],l[2],e[2]);
  compare1 cp1_4(A[3],B[3],g[3],l[3],e[3]);
  compare1 cp1_5(A[4],B[4],g[4],l[4],e[4]);
  compare1 cp1_6(A[5],B[5],g[5],l[5],e[5]);
  compare1 cp1_7(A[6],B[6],g[6],l[6],e[6]);
  compare1 cp1_8(A[7],B[7],g[7],l[7],e[7]);
  compare1 cp1_9(A[8],B[8],g[8],l[8],e[8]);
  compare1 cp1_10(A[9],B[9],g[9],l[9],e[9]);
  compare1 cp1_11(A[10],B[10],g[10],l[10],e[10]);
  compare1 cp1_12(A[11],B[11],g[11],l[11],e[11]);
  compare1 cp1_13(A[12],B[12],g[12],l[12],e[12]);
  compare1 cp1_14(A[13],B[13],g[13],l[13],e[13]);
  compare1 cp1_15(A[14],B[14],g[14],l[14],e[14]);
  compare1 cp1_16(A[15],B[15],g[15],l[15],e[15]);
  compare1 cp1_17(A[16],B[16],g[16],l[16],e[16]);
  compare1 cp1_18(A[17],B[17],g[17],l[17],e[17]);
  compare1 cp1_19(A[18],B[18],g[18],l[18],e[18]);
  compare1 cp1_20(A[19],B[19],g[19],l[19],e[19]);
  compare1 cp1_21(A[20],B[20],g[20],l[20],e[20]);
  compare1 cp1_22(A[21],B[21],g[21],l[21],e[21]);
  compare1 cp1_23(A[22],B[22],g[22],l[22],e[22]);
  compare1 cp1_24(A[23],B[23],g[23],l[23],e[23]);
  compare1 cp1_25(A[24],B[24],g[24],l[24],e[24]);
  compare1 cp1_26(A[25],B[25],g[25],l[25],e[25]);
  compare1 cp1_27(A[26],B[26],g[26],l[26],e[26]);
  compare1 cp1_28(A[27],B[27],g[27],l[27],e[27]);
  compare1 cp1_29(A[28],B[28],g[28],l[28],e[28]);
  compare1 cp1_30(A[29],B[29],g[29],l[29],e[29]);
  compare1 cp1_31(A[30],B[30],g[30],l[30],e[30]);
  compare1 cp1_32(A[31],B[31],g[31],l[31],e[31]);

  compare2 cp2_1(g[0],g[1],l[0],l[1],e[0],e[1],g[32],l[32],e[32]);
  compare2 cp2_2(g[2],g[3],l[2],l[3],e[2],e[3],g[33],l[33],e[33]);
  compare2 cp2_3(g[4],g[5],l[4],l[5],e[4],e[5],g[34],l[34],e[34]);
  compare2 cp2_4(g[6],g[7],l[6],l[7],e[6],e[7],g[35],l[35],e[35]);
  compare2 cp2_5(g[8],g[9],l[8],l[9],e[8],e[9],g[36],l[36],e[36]);
  compare2 cp2_6(g[10],g[11],l[10],l[11],e[10],e[11],g[37],l[37],e[37]);
  compare2 cp2_7(g[12],g[13],l[12],l[13],e[12],e[13],g[38],l[38],e[38]);
  compare2 cp2_8(g[14],g[15],l[14],l[15],e[14],e[15],g[39],l[39],e[39]);
  compare2 cp2_9(g[16],g[17],l[16],l[17],e[16],e[17],g[40],l[40],e[40]);
  compare2 cp2_10(g[18],g[19],l[18],l[19],e[18],e[19],g[41],l[41],e[41]);
  compare2 cp2_11(g[20],g[21],l[20],l[21],e[20],e[21],g[42],l[42],e[42]);
  compare2 cp2_12(g[22],g[23],l[22],l[23],e[22],e[23],g[43],l[43],e[43]);
  compare2 cp2_13(g[24],g[25],l[24],l[25],e[24],e[25],g[44],l[44],e[44]);
  compare2 cp2_14(g[26],g[27],l[26],l[27],e[26],e[27],g[45],l[45],e[45]);
  compare2 cp2_15(g[28],g[29],l[28],l[29],e[28],e[29],g[46],l[46],e[46]);
  compare2 cp2_16(g[30],g[31],l[30],l[31],e[30],e[31],g[47],l[47],e[47]);

  compare2 cp3_1(g[32],g[33],l[32],l[33],e[32],e[33],g[48],l[48],e[48]);
  compare2 cp3_2(g[34],g[35],l[34],l[35],e[34],e[35],g[49],l[49],e[49]);
  compare2 cp3_3(g[36],g[37],l[36],l[37],e[36],e[37],g[50],l[50],e[50]);
  compare2 cp3_4(g[38],g[39],l[38],l[39],e[38],e[39],g[51],l[51],e[51]);
  compare2 cp3_5(g[40],g[41],l[40],l[41],e[40],e[41],g[52],l[52],e[52]);
  compare2 cp3_6(g[42],g[43],l[42],l[43],e[42],e[43],g[53],l[53],e[53]);
  compare2 cp3_7(g[44],g[45],l[44],l[45],e[44],e[45],g[54],l[54],e[54]);
  compare2 cp3_8(g[46],g[47],l[46],l[47],e[46],e[47],g[55],l[55],e[55]);

  compare2 cp4_1(g[48],g[49],l[48],l[49],e[48],e[49],g[56],l[56],e[56]);
  compare2 cp4_2(g[50],g[51],l[50],l[51],e[50],e[51],g[57],l[57],e[57]);
  compare2 cp4_3(g[52],g[53],l[52],l[53],e[52],e[53],g[58],l[58],e[58]);
  compare2 cp4_4(g[54],g[55],l[54],l[55],e[54],e[55],g[59],l[59],e[59]);

  compare2 cp5_1(g[56],g[57],l[56],l[57],e[56],e[57],g[60],l[60],e[60]);
  compare2 cp5_2(g[58],g[59],l[58],l[59],e[58],e[59],g[61],l[61],e[61]);

  compare2 cp6(g[60],g[61],l[60],l[61],e[60],e[61],G_temp,L_temp,E_temp);

  assign G=~G_temp;
  assign L=~L_temp;
  assign E=~E_temp;

task compare1(
  input a,b,
  output g,l,e);
  reg w1;
begin
    w1= ~(a&b);
    g= ~(a&w1);
    l= ~(b&w1);
    e= ~(g&l);
end
endtask

task compare2(
  input a0,a1,b0,b1,c0,c1,
  output gg,ll,ee);
  reg p1,p2;
begin
   p1=c1|a0;
   p2=c1|b0;
   gg=p1&a1;
   ll=p2&b1;
   ee=c0|c1;
end
endtask

endmodule 

module testbench;
reg [31:0]A;
reg [31:0]B;
wire [61:0] g,l,e;
wire G,L,E;
main_fn  mf1(A,B,G,L,E,g,l,e);
initial
begin
$monitor(,$time," a0 = %b b0= %b A=%b, B=%b, G=%b, L=%b, E=%b,g=%b,l=%b,e=%b",A[0],B[0],A,B,G,L,E,g,l,e);
#0  A=32'b01010101010101010101010101010101;B=32'b10101010101010101010101010101010;
#100  A=32'b10101010101010101010101010101010;B=32'b01010101010101010101010101010101;
#200  A=32'b01010101010101010101010101010101;B=32'b01010101010101010101010101010101;
end
endmodule
```

And my test bench is giving the following output

```
run -all
#                     0 a0 = 1 b0= 0 A=01010101010101010101010101010101, B=10101010101010101010101010101010, G=0, L=1, E=0,g=11111111111111111111111111111x101010101010101010101010101010x0,l=00000000000000000000000000000x010101010101010101010101010101x1,e=111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111x1
#                   100 a0 = 0 b0= 1 A=10101010101010101010101010101010, B=01010101010101010101010101010101, G=1, L=0, E=0,g=00000000000000000000000000000x010101010101010101010101010101x1,l=11111111111111111111111111111x101010101010101010101010101010x0,e=111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111x1
#                   300 a0 = 1 b0= 1 A=01010101010101010101010101010101, B=01010101010101010101010101010101, G=x, L=x, E=x,g=1x111x1111111x111111111111111x111111111111111111111111111111x1,l=1x111x1111111x111111111111111x111111111111111111111111111111x1,e=0x000x0000000x000000000000000x000000000000000000000000000000x0
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Also, verilog has `for` loops - you should check them out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change (lower-case L's):

```
  compare1 cp1_2(A[l],B[l],g[1],l[1],e[1]);
```

to (1's):

```
  compare1 cp1_2(A[1],B[1],g[1],l[1],e[1]);
```